# Download php7 from comand line slackware

Tags: php, slackware

I tried download a php7 package to install on slackware, with following command:

```
wget "http://php.net/get/php-7.1.3.tar.gz/from/a/mirror"
```

The result is a `mirror` file, if i made again is `mirror.1`...

How i can execute installpkg on this file ?

Comment: Maybe remove "/from/a/mirror" in your command.

Comment: Thats-work sorry my newb question, i just copy link from site, if i put without /from/a/mirror on brower url redirect to another page not donwload, but on command line this work good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's normal – wget just uses the last path component as the filename.

You can use `--trust-server-names` to make it use whatever filename the server suggests (like web browsers do), or `-O php-7.1.3.tar.gz` to specify it yourself.

---

However, you have the wrong URL here. Both `http://php.net/get/php-7.1.3.tar.gz` and `http://php.net/get/php-7.1.3.tar.gz/from/a/mirror` merely lead to HTML webpages. You should visit that page *in a web browser* and pick a specific download URL. For example:

```
wget --trust-server-names http://dk2.php.net/get/php-7.1.3.tar.gz/from/this/mirror
```

Comment: U certo eu tento descompact xz, mas não é xz é um arquivo html ... Mas como eu posso ver o rela url, se quando eu clicar no link eles download automático, e não pode ver rela url como você colocar no seu exemplo ? Sorry my bad i see now, navigate from a mirror... tks man